# Debug Assertion Failed with contours.erase

Tags: erase, assertion

this is my code, what wrong with it?

itc=contours.erase(itc) make this error. and i run it in debug mode.
i use open cv 2.4.10 and visual studio 2013.
and call stack is:

msvcp120d.dll!5bd8dfdd()    Unknown
[Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing, no symbols loaded for msvcp120d.dll]

> ConsoleApplication3.exe!main(int argc, char * * argv) Line 84  C++

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "highgui.h"
#include "opencv2\opencv.hpp"
#include "opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp"




using namespace cv;
using namespace std;


bool verifySizes(RotatedRect mr){

float error = 0.4;
//Spain car plate size: 52x11 aspect 4,7272
float aspect = 4.7272;
//Set a min and max area. All other patchs are discarded
int min = 15 * aspect * 15; // minimum area
int max = 125 * aspect * 125; // maximum area
//Get only patchs that match to a respect ratio.
float rmin = aspect - aspect*error;
float rmax = aspect + aspect*error;


int area = mr.size.height * mr.size.width;
float r = (float)mr.size.width / (float)mr.size.height;
if (r < 1)
    r = (float)mr.size.height / (float)mr.size.width;

if ((area < min || area > max) || (r < rmin || r > rmax)){
    return false;
}
else{
    return true;
}

}




 int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

cv::Mat image = imread("d://untitled.jpg", cv::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
cv::imshow("orginal", image);

cv::equalizeHist(image, image);
cv::imshow("histeq", image);
cv::Canny(image, image, 100, 300, 3, true);
cv::imshow("canny", image);
Mat img_sobel;
cv::Sobel(image, img_sobel, CV_8U, 1, 0, 3, 1, 0, BORDER_DEFAULT);
cv::imshow("sobel", img_sobel);

Mat element = getStructuringElement(MORPH_RECT, Size(17, 3));
morphologyEx(img_sobel, img_sobel, CV_MOP_CLOSE, element);
cv::imshow("morph", img_sobel);


vector< vector< Point> > contours;
findContours(img_sobel,
    contours, // a vector of contours
    CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, // retrieve the external contours
    CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);


vector<vector<Point>>::iterator itc = contours.begin();
vector<RotatedRect> rects;

while (itc != contours.end()) {
    //Create bounding rect of object
    RotatedRect mr = minAreaRect(Mat(*itc));
    if (!verifySizes(mr)){
        itc = contours.erase(itc);
    }
    else{
        ++itc;
        rects.push_back(mr);
    }
}



cv::waitKey();
}
```

Comment: my problem solved with visual studio 2010!